# How to organize Typescript type definitions for a function module with lots of private classes?

Tags: typescript, type-definition

I'm writing type definitions for a library I don't own called [fessonia](http://github.com/tedconf/fessonia/). I have some experience doing this, but this library is organized differently than others I've worked with, and I'm not sure how to approach it.

This library's `index.js` is small:

```js
const getFessonia = (opts = {}) => {
  require('./lib/util/config')(opts);
  const Fessonia = {
    FFmpegCommand: require('./lib/ffmpeg_command'),
    FFmpegInput: require('./lib/ffmpeg_input'),
    FFmpegOutput: require('./lib/ffmpeg_output'),
    FilterNode: require('./lib/filter_node'),
    FilterChain: require('./lib/filter_chain')
  };
  return Fessonia;
}

module.exports = getFessonia;
```

It exports a function which returns an object, each member of which is a class. (Every file I've encountered in the lib so far uses default exports.) I've started with the [module function template](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-function-d-ts.html), but I'm struggling to find harmony among some of my guiding principles:

- **The type definitions should promote best practices for using this library.** What I mean by this is that I will not bother to create definitions for methods that are flagged as `@private` or which are otherwise not intended/recommended for external use. Per the library documentation, `getFessonia` is the only public interface to this library. While there's nothing stopping a developer from importing `FFmpegCommand` directly, one shouldn't (because, for example, the config that would have been set in `getFessonia` won't have been set, and errors will likely result).
- **The type definitions should be useful.** Downstream developers should be able to assign types to their variables à la:

```
import getFessonia from '@tedconf/fessonia';
// note the type assignment
const config: getFessonia.ConfigOpts = {
    debug: true,
};
const { FFmpegCommand, FFmpegInput, FFmpegOutput } = getFessonia(config);
```

- **The layout of your declaration files should mirror the layout of the library.** Per [official recommendation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html#library-file-layout).

So far the approach I've taken is to create `.d.ts` files for each `.js` file required to make useful type definitions, then import those into `index.d.ts` and re-export as needed in the `getFessonia` namespace. For example, in order to provide a type definition for the `opts` argument, I needed to read `lib/util/config`, which has a default export `getConfig`. Its type file ends up looking something like this:

```
import getLogger from './logger';

export = getConfig;

/**
 * Get the config object, optionally updated with new options
 */
declare function getConfig(options?: Partial<getConfig.Config>): getConfig.Config;

declare namespace getConfig {
    export interface Config {
      ffmpeg_bin: string;
      ffprobe_bin: string;
      debug: boolean;
      log_warnings: boolean;
      logger: getLogger.Logger;
    }
}
```

... and I use it in `index.d.ts` like this:

```
import getConfig from './lib/util/config';

export = getFessonia;

/**
 * Main function interface to the library. Returns object of classes when called.
 */
declare function getFessonia(opts?: Partial<getFessonia.ConfigOpts>): getFessonia.Fessonia;

declare namespace getFessonia {
    export interface Fessonia {
        // TODO
        FFmpegCommand: any;
        FFmpegInput: any;
        FFmpegOutput: any;
        FilterNode: any;
        FilterChain: any;
    }
    // note I've just aliased and re-exported this
    export type ConfigOpts = Partial<getConfig.Config>;
}
```

Reasons I think I might be headed down the wrong path:

- I don't think I need a definition for the function `getConfig`, especially since I don't want to promote its direct usage. Does it matter that `lib/util/config` has a default export? Should I just export the `Config` interface directly and re-export that from `index.d.ts`? Or maybe I'll delete the function definition and keep the `Config` interface under the namespace; that way, should `getConfig` become a public function in the future, I can just add the definition for the function.
- Re-exporting under the `getFessonia` namespace is tedious and not especially elegant.
- I could end up with a lot of nesting (and aliasing) under `getFessonia`. For example, the constructor for `FFmpegOutput` takes an argument which is really just a map of arguments for an internal class `FFmpegOption`, so downstream code could maybe end up looking something like:

```
import getFessonia from '@tedconf/fessonia';

const { FFmpegCommand, FFmpegInput, FFmpegOutput } = getFessonia();
// note the deep nesting
const outputOptions: getFessonia.FFmpeg.Output.Options = { /* some stuff */ };
const output = new FFmpegOutput('some/path', outputOptions);
```

- It's not very intuitive for the defintion of the argument to `getFessonia` and the shape of `FFmpegOutput` to be siblings.
- I'm making up the `FFmpeg` namespace for organizational/naming-conflict-avoidance reasons.

You made it to the end! Thanks for reading this far. While I suspect there isn't one "right" answer, I look forward to reading about approaches others have taken, and I'm happy to be pointed to articles or relevant code repositories where I might learn by example. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want a namespace here? Would `import getFessonia, { FessoniaConfigOptions } from 'fessionia'` work? Flatter type declarations are usually way easier to manage.

Comment: No, I'm not sure! The approach you described works, though I could have sworn I tried it before and got compile errors. Do you have any advice for communicating the shapes of the child classes, their args, etc? Should I define those in separate files then import them into index.d.ts and re-export them?

Comment: As you say, you can approach this in a lot of different ways. You also have many questions here, so you may want to split them up. You can declare functions (e.g. `getConfig` without exporting them. You can also export types for utility purposes, e.g. `export type FFmpegOutputOptions = getFessonia.FFmpeg.Output.Options`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@alex-wayne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62076/alex-wayne)'s comment helped reset my brain. Thank you.

For some reason I was writing my type definitions as though the library's usage of default exports meant I couldn't also export other things from my `.d.ts` files. Not enough sleep, maybe!

Anyway, in addition to default-exporting the function `getFessonia` I ended up exporting an interface `Fessonia` to describe the return value as well as a namespace of the same name ([more on TypeScript's combining behavior](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/deep-dive.html#simple-combinations-one-name-multiple-meanings)) to provide types for `getFessonia`'s options as well as various other entities provided by the library. `index.d.ts` ended up looking like:

```
import { FessoniaConfig } from './lib/util/config';
import FFmpegCommand from './lib/ffmpeg_command';
import FFmpegInput from './lib/ffmpeg_input';
import FFmpegOutput from './lib/ffmpeg_output';
import FilterChain from './lib/filter_chain';
import FilterNode from './lib/filter_node';

/** Main function interface to the library. Returns object of classes when called. */
export default function getFessonia(opts?: Partial<Fessonia.ConfigOpts>): Fessonia;

export interface Fessonia {
  FFmpegCommand: typeof FFmpegCommand;
  FFmpegInput: typeof FFmpegInput;
  FFmpegOutput: typeof FFmpegOutput;
  FilterChain: typeof FilterChain;
  FilterNode: typeof FilterNode;
}

// re-export only types (i.e., not constructors) to prevent direct instantiation
import type FFmpegCommandType from './lib/ffmpeg_command';
import type FFmpegError from './lib/ffmpeg_error';
import type FFmpegInputType from './lib/ffmpeg_input';
import type FFmpegOutputType from './lib/ffmpeg_output';
import type FilterNodeType from './lib/filter_node';
import type FilterChainType from './lib/filter_chain';
export namespace Fessonia {
    export type ConfigOpts = Partial<FessoniaConfig>;

    export {
      FFmpegCommandType as FFmpegCommand,
      FFmpegError,
      FFmpegInputType as FFmpegInput,
      FFmpegOutputType as FFmpegOutput,
      FilterChainType as FilterChain,
      FilterNodeType as FilterNode,
    };
}
```

For the classes that are part of the `Fessonia` object, my general approach was to create a type definition for each one (leaving out private members) and export it. If the class functions had parameters with complex types, I'd create definitions for those and export them in a namespace with the same name as the class, e.g.:

```
// abridged version of types/lib/ffmpeg_input.d.ts
export default FFmpegInput;

declare class FFmpegInput {
    constructor(url: FFmpegInput.UrlParam, options?: FFmpegInput.Options);
}

declare namespace FFmpegInput {
    export type Options = Map<string, FFmpegOption.OptionValue> | { [key: string]: FFmpegOption.OptionValue };
    export type UrlParam = string | FilterNode | FilterChain | FilterGraph;
}
```

Because of the re-exporting of the types at the bottom of `index.d.ts`, this downstream code becomes possible:

```
import getFessonia, { Fessonia } from '@tedconf/fessonia';

const { FFmpegCommand, FFmpegInput, FFmpegOutput } = getFessonia();
// note the type assignment
const outputOptions: Fessonia.FFmpegOutput.Options = { /* some stuff */ };
const output = new FFmpegOutput('some/path', outputOptions);
const cmd = new FFmpegCommand(commandOpts);
```

While this isn't drastically different from what I had originally, it does feel like an improvement. I didn't have to invent too many new organizational structures; the type names are consistent with the structure of the codebase (with the addition of the `Fessonia` namespace). And it's readable.

My first pass at typing this library is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/tedconf/fessonia/pull/44/commits/65875f6d7119bba5341dceb71b8a26cd52b219e3).

Thanks to everyone who commented and got me thinking differently.